# OMake bin directory

Tags: ocaml, omake

I am trying to have omake build stuff in my bin directory. I tried

```
LIB = ../bin/mylib
.DEFAULT: $(OCamlLibrary $(LIB), $(FILES))
```

But only the .a and .cmxa end up in bin, all the .cmx .cmi and .o end up in src. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong.  OMake's built-in OCaml related rules compile each module and produce its objects (.cmo, .cmi, .cmx and .o) in the same directory of the source code.

`$(OCamlLibrary $(LIB), $(FILES))` function link these module objects and produce library files `$(LIB).cma`, `$(LIB).cmxa` and `$(LIB).a`, just like you have seen.

If you want to change the destination directory of object files, you have to fix the build rules for OCaml.  They are defined in `OCaml.om` found in OMake's library directory, but I have to say that this is very challenging.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do a copy/symlink rule after the `$(OCamlLibrary ..)` target finishes?